# Python / Django - Get List Value With Index From Object Variable Value

Tags: python, django, django-templates

I have a list that is passed into a template.  I want to access a value with a specific index.  Problem is the list is accessed with dot notation in the template...

For example:

```
object = { id: 1 }
list = [ "zero", "one" ]
print list[ object.id ] ## one
```

Once the list is in the template you access values by index with dot notation.

```
list.1 ## one
list[ object.id ] ## this doesn't work
list.object.id ## this doesn't work obv.
```

How can I access the value "one" with the index of "1"?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Is the key in your dictionary supposed to be  the variable `id` or the string `"id"`?  If it's `"id"` then I think the third one would work.

Answer (score 2):

I don't think this is possible with Django's template language. It is pretty limited by design.

You can do this by putting that code in the view, and passing the value of `list[object.id]` down to the template when you render it.

Answer (score 1):

I don't quite agree it's impossible.

You can create template tag, which will accept two arguments and will inject a new
variable into a template context.

The usage can look as follows:
   {% get_list_member list object.id as list_member %}

then you can use list_member as ordinary template variable {{ list_member }}

check the implementation of standard url template tag, which also allows to assign url into
template context variable for later use.